# Why did Littlefinger not ask for evidence in trial?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

We know Littlefinger as one of the wisest and wickedest characters in *Game of Thrones*, but in "The Dragon and the Wolf" (*Game of Thrones*. S07E07),

> Littlefinger dies at the hands of Arya, following Sansa's sentence.

But why did Littlefinger not demand any evidence to prove the Starks' accusations? Is it enough that Bran said the exact words Littlefinger said to Ned, back in season 1, which eventually lead to Ned's death? Is there any other event in that scene that I missed that means Littlefinger doesn't need any hard evidence to be found guilty of his crimes?